# Mockito - when thenReturn

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm new to the Mockito library and I can't understand the following syntax:
before the test I defined -

```
when(CLASS.FUNCTION(PARAMETERS)).thenReturn(RETURN_VALUE)
```

And the actual test is  -

```
assertSame(RETURN_VALUE, CLASS.FUNCTION(PARAMETERS))
```

Don't I just set the return value of the function with the first line of code (`when... thenReturn`) to be `RETURN_VALUE`? If the answer is yes, then of course `assertSame` will be true and the test will pass, what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you asking for the difference between these two lines of code? Is "CLASS.FUNCTION" a static method? Give a more realistic example and clarify your question.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] along with your expected results and actual results. As it stands I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you getting an error message? One thing I will say is you may want to review some testing/mocking tutorials. You should use when/then for what you've mocked (the unit under test's dependencies). Then you test does the execution and verification.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The point of Mockito (or any form of mocking, actually) isn't to mock the code you're checking, but to replace external dependencies with mocked code.

E.g., consider you have this trivial interface:

```
public interface ValueGenerator {
    int getValue();
}
```

And this is your code that uses it:

```
public class Incrementor {
    public int increment(ValueGenerator vg) {
        return vg.getValue() + 1;
    }
}
```

You want to test your `Incrementor` logic without depending on any specific implementation of `ValueGenerator`.
That's where Mockito comes into play:

```
// Mock the dependencies:
ValueGenerator vgMock = Mockito.mock(ValueGenerator.class);
when(vgMock.getValue()).thenReturn(7);

// Test your code:
Incrementor inc = new Incrementor();
assertEquals(8, inc.increment(vgMock));
```

Comment: I was searching for this answer for a very long time. +1

Comment: I've seen lots of only mock tested examples. It's quite confusing and pointless only to test the mocks, right? For instance,  return vg.getValue(); instead of  return vg.getValue() + 1; basically tests nothing as far i get and there are so many examples that does that

Comment: Thanks for a nice and illustrative example